# How to schedule AutoSys job to run between 1:00 AM EST till 1:30 AM EST

Tags: autosys

I have scenario where i want to create a Autosys scheduling job.

which should run from `Monday till Friday` only that too between time `1:00 AM EST till 1:30 AM EST`

Should check every 10 minutes from 1:00 till 1:30 AM EST only

**I tried this :**

```
run_window : 11:00-11:30
```

How to achieve that every 10 minutes ? and calendar creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Day and time condition for this scenario can be configured at job level and no explicit calendar creation is required.

```
insert_job: WeekDay_MidNight_Job
job_type: CMD 
machine: localhost
command: bash /absolute_path/script_name.sh
run_window : 00:55-01:35                     /* Job activates 5 min prior to actual run */
start_mins: 0,10,20,30                       /* Of every 0,10,20,30 minutes of the hour, the job gets triggered, for this case 01:00, 01:10, 01:20 and 01:30 */
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr                 /* Days of the week */
exclude_calendar: Holiday_Calendar_Name      /* Skips run on defined holidays */
timezone: US/Eastern
```

Use timezone attribute from the "tz database name" column from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

The same is also possible with use of extended calendar and cycles.

Autosys User Manual [here](https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/cadocs/0/CA%20Workload%20Automation%20AE%20Release%2011%203%206%20-%20Public%20Access-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/PDF/WA_AE_User_ENU.pdf)

Comment: Can you show how to add holiday calendar date to above ... i dont want the job to be running on those holiday calendar dates how to achieve this ?

Comment: Thanks for the solution will try to implement